# How to read back JPG with multiple data created in Unity? ( C# )

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, encoding, jpeg, decoding

I'm really sorry if this has been asked before, or if it is obvious, but I'm not entirely sure how to progress here. Please excuse the length of the question.

For a research project, my intention is to create a JPG image that contains after the JPG data a small plain text and another image as well. This image would be used later as an AR marker that 'contains' all the data to be displayed. I read that this could also be achieved with Stenography, but encrypting is not necessarily the goal, I think.

So far, using various other methods found here, the script can create a readable image that adds the byte[] data of the other content right after the first JPG, but I'm not entirely sure how to read it back.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Crosstales.FB;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System;
using System.Text;

public class JPGMan : MonoBehaviour {

public UnityEngine.UI.Image markerThumb;
public UnityEngine.UI.Image mediaThumb;
public UnityEngine.UI.InputField descF;

Encoding u8 = Encoding.UTF8;

public void initLoadMarker()
{
    string markerExt = "";
    string markerPath = FileBrowser.OpenSingleFile("Image for Marker", "", markerExt);
    StartCoroutine(loadMarker(markerPath));
    Debug.Log(markerPath);
}

public void initLoadMedia()
{
    string mediaExt = "";
    string mediaPath = FileBrowser.OpenSingleFile("Image for Media", "", mediaExt);
    StartCoroutine(loadMedia(mediaPath));
    Debug.Log(mediaPath);
}

IEnumerator loadMarker(string mPath)
{
    WWW markerWWW;

    using (markerWWW = new WWW("File:///" + mPath))
    {
        yield return markerWWW;
        Debug.Log(markerWWW.isDone);
        Rect protoRect = new Rect(Vector2.zero, new Vector2(markerWWW.texture.width, markerWWW.texture.height));
        Sprite protoSprite = Sprite.Create(markerWWW.texture, protoRect, Vector2.zero);
        markerThumb.sprite = protoSprite;
        markerThumb.preserveAspect = true;
    }
}

IEnumerator loadMedia(string mPath)
{
    WWW mediaWWW;

    using (mediaWWW = new WWW("File:///" + mPath))
    {
        yield return mediaWWW;
        Debug.Log(mediaWWW.isDone);
        Rect protoRect = new Rect(Vector2.zero, new Vector2(mediaWWW.texture.width, mediaWWW.texture.height));
        Sprite protoSprite = Sprite.Create(mediaWWW.texture, protoRect, Vector2.zero);
        mediaThumb.sprite = protoSprite;
        mediaThumb.preserveAspect = true;
    }
}

public void encodeJPG()
{
    string finalExt = "jpg";

    string finalPath = FileBrowser.SaveFile("Save Marker", "", "aMARKER", finalExt);

    Texture2D protoJPG = new Texture2D((int)mediaThumb.sprite.textureRect.width, (int)mediaThumb.sprite.textureRect.height);
    Color[] pixels = mediaThumb.sprite.texture.GetPixels((int)mediaThumb.sprite.textureRect.x, (int)mediaThumb.sprite.textureRect.y, (int)mediaThumb.sprite.textureRect.width, (int)mediaThumb.sprite.textureRect.height);
    protoJPG.SetPixels(pixels);
    protoJPG.Apply();

    Texture2D protoMarker = new Texture2D((int)markerThumb.sprite.textureRect.width, (int)markerThumb.sprite.textureRect.height);
    Color[] markerPixels = markerThumb.sprite.texture.GetPixels((int)markerThumb.sprite.textureRect.x, (int)markerThumb.sprite.textureRect.y, (int)markerThumb.sprite.textureRect.width, (int)markerThumb.sprite.textureRect.height);
    protoMarker.SetPixels(markerPixels);
    protoMarker.Apply();


    byte[] markerBytes = protoMarker.EncodeToJPG(100);
    byte[] imgBytes = protoJPG.EncodeToJPG(100);
    byte[] textBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(descF.text);

    byte[] finalBytes = new byte[markerBytes.Length + textBytes.Length + imgBytes.Length];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(markerBytes, 0, finalBytes, 0, markerBytes.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(textBytes, 0, finalBytes, markerBytes.Length, textBytes.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(imgBytes, 0, finalBytes, markerBytes.Length + textBytes.Length, imgBytes.Length);

    File.WriteAllBytes(finalPath, finalBytes);

}

public void decodeJPG()
{
    string inExt = "jpg";

    string inPath = FileBrowser.OpenSingleFile("Open Marker", "", inExt);
    StartCoroutine(loadMarkerImage(inPath));
}

IEnumerator loadMarkerImage(string inPath_)
{

    byte[] bytesFile;
    char[] lookFiles = new char[] {'J','F','I','F'};

    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(inPath_))
    {
        yield return fs;
        bytesFile = new byte[20];
        fs.Read(bytesFile, 0, 20);
        fs.Close();
    }

    byte[] searchBytes = u8.GetBytes(lookFiles);

    List<int> rList = IndexOfSequence(bytesFile, searchBytes, 0);
    Debug.Log(rList[0].ToString());

}
```

I'm thinking that I could maybe find a way to write to the JPG spec's APP0 marker, but I haven't found much about doing this specifically in Unity. Another could be to loop through the whole byte[] to find the headers and thus differentiate the data, although I read that reading all the bytes in one operation is not particularly fast.

Finally, I was thinking of appending the serialization of a class that contains the extra data, making it possible to deserialize it and just refer to it as properties of the class. But that's probably a bad idea.

I am aware this is very unusual, and I don't mind as well just using a regular database and link the images to that data.

Is there anyone that could help with this matter? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: I share an idea.Do not write info into jpg. Instead we create extra file describe the specify jpg and use md5 or filename binds extra file and jpg.Such as unity meta files.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I see, it could work a lot better like this! Never thought of that. Is there, by chance, any example of such an implementation?

Comment: I'm not sure.You could search network for implementsation.